# why App.cs run in react in every component but not other css component?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs

My question is simple that
when imported 'App.css' it runs in any class Component required that .class is in the app.css file
but if I want to use any other CSS file I have to use CSS-loader and style-loader .
So why App.css is given permission to be run in every component

Answer (score 0):

**why App.cs run in react in every component but not other css component?**

**Ans**

Because App.css is main module of react it will load when your react app is loaded thats why it will load with all components

You can say it global file for all react components